# Overstating Interest Rates?

Tags: finance

I'm fact checking my analysis, so there's only one possible answer in that I'm either right or way out in left field (wrong).

A friend of mine mentioned this bitcoin lending site and I looked at it to see if the returns they're promising are correct.  When I look at [this loan](https://www.bitbond.com/listings/1VW9TK3ZEE) for this question's purpose, I see that it offers a 19.47% return ([this is how their interest rates are calculated](http://help.bitbond.com/knowledgebase/articles/529072-how-are-interest-payments-calculated)).  What I see is that the borrower borrowed 3 BTC and paid back the 2.99998200 BTC plus 0.37685100 in interest.  That is a 12.561775% return, not 19.47%, based on my math and this is a one-year loan (they adjust when it's less than a year).

Now, it's possible that the user paid some early, which would have reduce his later payments, but I haven't heard back from the company when I asked them about this several weeks ago, so I wanted to fact check the math I'm doing because I'm getting a ~7% miss.  Thanks!

Comment: It's because he paid it back in monthly installments. For this you have to use the annuity formula + balloon payment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity

Comment: @MatthewEr Thanks Matthew; so that does mean then that the investor didn't get the 19.47% APR return; the actual return was lower because he paid it back in monthly installments.

Comment: No the rate of 19.47% is correct.